# change ascii to string after adding number to it

Tags: java, string, char, int

I am trying to reform a string from ascii characters. I noticed when I break down ascii it matches the number with the ascii char, this changes when I tried to do (c+=c+0) on it as seen below, I tried to revert back to the original string but it doesn't seems to work. I was wondering does the ascii number change when you append it to a string?

```
StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
char c = "e".charAt(0);
System.out.println(c);   //'e'
System.out.println(c+0); //101 -ascii
b.append(c+=c+0);
char d = b.charAt(0);
System.out.println(d-=d+0);   //blank
```

Comment: `d-=d-0`?? Perhaps you meant `d+0`?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Your code has lots of strange things going on, like `b.append(c += c+0)`... it will be helpful if you tell us what you're trying to do on each line, what happens, and what you expected to happen.

Comment: well is just (c = c+c+0) and yes you can write it as c*=2 but currently I have cut the method into small pieces for debugging so c*=2 will not work for the full form. I am trying to get String b back to the original form. 'e'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- When you use `+` to sum a `char` with and `int`,  the result will be promoted
  to `int`.
- When you use [compound assignment operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2) `+=`, the result will be converted to **left**
  operand data type(in this case, `char`)

This is what happens with your code:

```
StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
char c = "e".charAt(0);
System.out.println(c);   //'e'
System.out.println(c+0); //101 -ascii
b.append(c+=c+0); // result of c+c+0 is int 202, it is converted to char Ê
char d = b.charAt(0); // char d = Ê
System.out.println(d-=d+0); // result of d-(d+0) is int 0, it will be converted to null
```

Comment: actually you are right, I missed that into a zero instead. System.out.println(String.valueOf(Character.toChars(d/2))); works

Comment: @logger were you responding to the right answer? Also, `System.out.println((char) (d/2));` is much simpler. All you need to do is cast the `int` expression `d/2` into a `char`.

Comment: @pkpnd Are you downvoting this answer? Is it not useful?

Comment: @user6690200 Your answer doesn't show the OP what the best code practices are. Converting a `char` to an `int` should be done with a cast; printing out `d-=d+0` is just asking for trouble.

Comment: @pkpnd I did not provide any suggestion. I'm telling him what happens with his code.

Comment: @user6690200 Your answer doesn't help the OP "revert back to the original string".

Comment: @pkpnd It does. If OP dose not know what is happening with his code, how can he found out how to solve it?  I did not provide a solution, but it does not mean it is not useful.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish, but hopefully this example helps you figure out what's going on:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
    char c = "e".charAt(0);
    System.out.println(c);   // e
    System.out.println((int) c); // 101
    char doubleC = (char) (c + c);
    b.append(doubleC);
    char d = b.charAt(0);
    System.out.println((int) d); // 202
    System.out.println(d - c); // 101
    System.out.println((char) (d - c)); // e
}
```

Whether a character is printed as a letter or its ASCII value depends on its type. You can see that `(int) c` casts the character to its `int` ASCII value. Your approach of `c+0` also does this but in a less intuitive way.

You also apparently want to "undo" your modification to `c`, but subtracting `d-d` always gives you `0`. You need to store your value of `c` and subtract that from `d`.

Comment: assume you dont have access to var c, just the string b to work with.

Comment: Well.. what are you trying to do? I can't help you solve your problem if _I don't know what your problem is_.

Comment: You can do `System.out.println(d / 2);`.

Comment: so I have a string, the encoding sequence is like this....it breaks string down into characters then it encrypt by doubles then add a integer sequence number. Then it pack back into a string. Now I am trying to recover that original string.

Comment: Then you need to reverse the "encryption" scheme. Suppose your encryption changes every character `c` to `2*c + n`. To decrypt, you need to reverse those operations in the reverse order: `(d - n) / 2`, where `d` is your encrypted character.

Answer (score 0):

+0s don't do anything because the character is underneath a number (so it's essentially like saying 101 + 0).

`d-=d+0` evaluates to `d = d - d + 0`, so (because we're manipulating chars) d - d = 0

If you wanted to get c from d, you'd have to do `d = d - c`, because 'c' is the difference between the initial and the final value.

So no, the ASCII number of a character doesn't change, you're just not doing the reverse calculation as you should be.

It's like saying: `x + y = z`,
 and then wondering why `z - z != y`.

You should be doing: `z - x = y`

@Edit
To add to your comment under pkpnd's answer - if you have only String b to work with, you'd still need to know the difference (i.e. by how much you increased/decreased the number) to reverse to the original chars.